# Undeserved Badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, badges, votes

I just logged into meta.J.SE and was promptly notified that I had received the "[Vox Populi](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/69/vox-populi)" badge. This seems impossible as I have only voted 9 times all week. Bug? [image: user's vote count]  (From my meta.J.SE user page)

Edit: It seems quite extensive:
None of these people have used 40 votes all week.
[image: list of those recently awarded the vox populi badge]

Comment: Hey, I just did too!!

Comment: Me, too, here on meta.J.SE. But not on meta.SO (or J.SE).

Comment: Apparently, there's a network-wide bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123165/vox-populi-badge-awarded-without-casting-any-vote http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123166/electorate-badges-for-everyone http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123159/vox-populi-badges-being-awarded-incorrectly

Comment: @msh210 really? I also, got one on meta.SO

Comment: @msh210 you probably didn't because you already got one there. You can only get one once.

Comment: @HodofHod Silly me. thanks for editing that in

Comment: I did not get one on meta.SO but that could be because I only have 20 votes total. It might be forgetting the 'per day' part.

Comment: @HodofHod, (re that I had one already) good point! `:-)`

Comment: I just got one on English.SE, but not on the meta there. Must be that it's forgotten the 'per day' requirement, as @DoubleAA said.

Comment: Thanks for the links, @HodofHod. Let me reiterate in bold so people know where to look: **This is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123159**, which will probably indicate resolution and other information before this question does.

Comment: Too bad it isn't giving me an Electorate badge for free!

Comment: @DoubleAA it is! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123159/vox-populi-badges-being-awarded-incorrectly

Comment: @HodofHod I know, but it isn't giving __me__! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just deployed a change that affects the voting badges.  This is why you see a number of these badges being awarded.

For more information about this change, you can see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/140548).

Note that there is a bug with Vox Populi only that is awarding too many of them, beyond the expected more for retroactive awards, and a fix is being deployed now.  The erroneous awards there will be cleaned up shortly.